# SDL mouse motion event provides inconsistent xrel, yrel values under mouse button down event type

Tags: c++, events, sdl, mouse

I try to make a 3D game by using SDL2 and OpenGL 4.6 core mode, but I found a problem that makes me confused, and I don't know how to fix it, the code is following below:

```
// SDL2 initialize
// Create a SDL2 window
// Create a OpenGL 4.6 core context
// GLAD initialize
// ImGui initialize

// SDL Settings
SDL_SetHintWithPriority(SDL_HINT_MOUSE_RELATIVE_MODE_WARP, "1", SDL_HINT_OVERRIDE);

// main loop
bool done = false;
bool relative = false;
while (!done) {
    SDL_Event event;
    while(SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
        if (event.type == SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN) {
            if (event.button.button == SDL_BUTTON_LEFT) {
                relative = true;
            }
        }
        if (event.type == SDL_MOUSEBUTTONUP) {
            if (event.button.button == SDL_BUTTON_LEFT) {
                relative = false;
            }
        }
        if (event.type == SDL_MOUSEMOTION) {
            std::cout << "Mouse Motion Triggered: (" + std::to_string(event.motion.xrel) +  " ," + std::to_string(event.motion.yrel) + ")" << std::endl;
        }
    }

    if (relative) {
        SDL_SetRelativeMouseMode(SDL_TRUE);
    } else {
        SDL_SetRelativeMouseMode(SDL_FALSE);
    }

    // Render ImGui

    SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window);
}
```

As you can see, when I hold the mouse left button down all the time, and then move the mouse from the left-top of the screen to the right-down of the screen, I expect the relative mouse motion return will be like this.

```
Mouse Motion Triggered: (11 ,6)
Mouse Motion Triggered: (13 ,8)
Mouse Motion Triggered: (14 ,8)
Mouse Motion Triggered: (14 ,8)
Mouse Motion Triggered: (16 ,9)
Mouse Motion Triggered: (15 ,7)
Mouse Motion Triggered: (11 ,6)
Mouse Motion Triggered: (10 ,6)
```

The relative coordinates x and y value both should be a positive number, but it's not, the actual result will be like this:

```
Mouse Motion Triggered: (1 ,1)
Mouse Motion Triggered: (2 ,2)
Mouse Motion Triggered: (-6 ,-4)
Mouse Motion Triggered: (3 ,3)
Mouse Motion Triggered: (1 ,1)
Mouse Motion Triggered: (-2 ,-3)
Mouse Motion Triggered: (2 ,2)
Mouse Motion Triggered: (1 ,1)
Mouse Motion Triggered: (-4 ,-4)
Mouse Motion Triggered: (3 ,3)
Mouse Motion Triggered: (-3 ,-3)
Mouse Motion Triggered: (1 ,1)
Mouse Motion Triggered: (-2 ,-2)
Mouse Motion Triggered: (1 ,2)
Mouse Motion Triggered: (-2 ,-2)
```

This causes my mouse position forces to lock in the middle of the screen, and then I try to fix this problem, I rewrite the code for the event handler like this:

```
if (event.type == SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN) {
    if (event.button.button == SDL_BUTTON_LEFT) {
        relative = true;
        std::cout << "relative: " << relative << std::endl;
    }
    if (event.button.button == SDL_BUTTON_RIGHT) {
        relative = false;
        std::cout << "relative: " << relative << std::endl;
    }
}
if (event.type == SDL_MOUSEBUTTONUP) {
    // Now this event is empty.
}
```

I realize if I just press down the mouse left button once, and move the mouse in the same direction, the whole functional works normally, but what if I hold the mouse left button all the time and move the mouse in the same direction, the relative mouse return value `event.motion.xrel` and `event.motion.yrel` will be very strange, these will give an oppositive direction that to force to make my mouse position back to the center of the screen, and I don't have any ideas why this happened.

What is the problem?

Environment details

- OS: Window 10
- C++: 2017
- Compiler: MSVC
- IDE: Clion
- SDL2: 2.0.14#3 (vcpkg install)

Comment: The mouse being moved to the center of the screen when in relative mode is to be expected. But it's weird that this automatic movement is reported to `SDL_MOUSEMOTION`. Maybe try not spamming `SDL_SetRelativeMouseMode` every frame? Call it once every time you want to change the mode.

Comment: I try to put `SDL_SetRelativeMouseMode(SDL_TRUE)` this code before the main loop, and then clean up the code which is binding with `SDL_KEYDOWN` and `SDL_KEYUP` events. Unfortunately, the `xrel` and `yrel` values still report weird coordinates.

The reason why I want to spam the relative mouse coordinates is I wonder to create an FPS style camera, and mouse to control the rotation of the camera, but I also want to design if I hold the mouse right button, the mouse cursor will be shown and stop to control the camera, control the GUI instead.

Answer (score 1):

I found the main reason that causes the `xrel` and `yrel` values to become so wried, that is `ImGui_ImplSDL2_NewFrame(window)`. When I comment out this code, the relative mouse report normally, but what if I add this line into the main loop, the relative mouse will report weird coordinate that force my mouse back to the center of the screen, I doubt maybe is the ImGui try to control the mouse event and it has a control conflict with something that I exactly don't know.

I saw the source code `imgui_impl_sdl.cpp`, but I still don't know why this will happen, the solution for this problem is I make a toggle key which is tapping the TAB key to control the mouse for camera or GUI.

Here is my latest code:

```
// SDL2 initialize
// Create a SDL2 window
// Create a OpenGL 4.6 core context
// GLAD initialize

// ImGui initialize
IMGUI_CHECKVERSION();
ImGui::CreateContext();
ImGui_ImplSDL2_InitForOpenGL(window, context);
ImGui_ImplOpenGL3_Init("#version 330");
ImGui::StyleColorsDark();
ImGuiIO &io = ImGui::GetIO();

// SDL Settings
SDL_SetHintWithPriority(SDL_HINT_MOUSE_RELATIVE_MODE_WARP, "1", SDL_HINT_OVERRIDE);
SDL_SetRelativeMouseMode(SDL_TRUE);

// main loop
bool done = false;
while (!done) {
    SDL_Event event;
    while(SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
        ImGui_ImplSDL2_ProcessEvent(&event);
        if (event.type == SDL_MOUSEMOTION) {
            std::cout << "Mouse Motion Triggered: (" + std::to_string(event.motion.xrel) +  " ," + std::to_string(event.motion.yrel) + ")" << std::endl;
        }
    }

    // Render ImGui
    ImGui_ImplOpenGL3_NewFrame();
    ImGui_ImplSDL2_NewFrame(window); // <-- this is the main reason
    //ImGui::NewFrame();
    //ImGui::Render();

    //ImGui_ImplOpenGL3_RenderDrawData(ImGui::GetDrawData());
    SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window);
}
// Delete ImGui and SDL Context, Window and SDL_QUIT()
```

ImGui version: 1.83

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I ran into this even without using ImGui, and I wanted to post the answer for anyone in the future that has the same problem.

If you accidentally call `SDL_SetRelativeMouseMode(SDL_TRUE);` *before* your `SDL_Init` call, you will get the behaviour OP described, where mouse motion events are followed by mouse motion events going the opposite direction, causing jittering if you are trying to make an FPS-game-like control scheme. There is no error messaging from SDL unfortunately, this is just the behaviour that you will end up with. The solution is just to do `SDL_SetRelativeMouseMode(SDL_TRUE);` *after* the init.

My project had a rogue `SDL_SetRelativeMouseMode(SDL_TRUE);` hiding in the constructor of a class that was instantiated before my `SDL_Init`, which made tracking it down very hard. If you have this problem, make sure you search your project for all references to that function!

Comment: Maybe report this as a bug to SDL?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I don't know if I would call this a bug so much as a symptom of the way we're expected to use SDL. You're not supposed to do anything before SDL_Init(), and while it would certainly be nice to have an error code returned, I don't know if it's reasonable to expect the library to implement a "hey, did you call SDL_Init() before calling me?" check in every API. (For the record I did consider reporting it as a bug, but just from SDL's POV I didn't think it was reasonable)